# If $X_n$ is a sequence of independent r.v., and $P(X_n = n^2) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n = \frac{1}{n}) = 1-\frac{1}{n}$, does it converge a.s.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X_n$ is a sequence of independent r.v., and $P(X_n = n^2) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $P(X_n = \frac{1}{n}) = 1-\frac{1}{n}$, does it converge a.s.?

I am having a hard time identifying the relation between $\omega$ and $X_n(\omega)$. Ideally, I would like to determine what $X_n(\omega)$ is, but it seems that no matter what $\omega$ I have, the sequence is completely dependent on $n$. Is this correct reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: First of all, what is your candidate for the limit of the sequence?

Comment: It would appear to be $0$?

Comment: Great, so could you put down what it would mean that $X_n$ converges a.s. to 0? It usually helps as a first step, to clarify what one actually needs to prove.

Comment: If $X_n$ were to converge almost surely to $0$, then we would have that $P(\omega: lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) = 0) =1$. It seems that it doesn't converge a.s. to $0$ since $P(X_n = n^2) = \frac{1}{n}$ ensures that there are infinitely many $\omega \in \Omega$ that would cause us to have a blown up $X_n$. Would it be prudent to use Borel-Cantelli then?

Comment: Yes, trying Borel-Cantelli is certainly a good idea here.

Comment: I know that Borel-Cantelli involves summing a sequence of events. But I am not clear what that sequence is. Would it be summing over $X_n$ or would it be summing only over $X_n: X_n = \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Try the events $A_n=[X_n=n^2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't use Borel-Cantelli, but this is the example we had in class to illustrate the difference in almost sure convergence versus convergence in probability.

If $X_n\overset{as}{\rightarrow} X$, then ,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(\underset{m\geq n}{\sup} |X_n-X|\}\geq \epsilon)=0$$ for all $\epsilon>0$.  Then,
$$=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{m\geq n}|X_n-X|\geq\epsilon\right)$$
$$=1-\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{m\geq n}|X_n-X|<\epsilon\right)$$ by de Morgan's law for taking complements.  If these events are independent, then the intersection changes to:
$$=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}1-\prod_{m=n}^k \mathbb{P}(|X_m-X|<\epsilon)$$

In your case, $\mathbb{P}(|X_i,X|<\epsilon)$ means $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1/i)= 1-\frac{1}{i}$.  Plugging in above, we get:
$$=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}1-\prod_{m=n}^k 1-\frac{1}{m}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}1-\prod_{m=n}^k \frac{m-1}{m}$$.
That product term becomes: $\frac{m-1}{m}\cdot\frac{m}{m+1}\cdot\frac{m+1}{m+2}\cdot...\cdot\frac{k-2}{k-1}\cdot\frac{k-1}{k}$.  Since the terms cancel, we are left with
$$=1-\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{m-1}{k}=1\neq 0$$.  But we needed the probability to be zero to get almost sure convergence.  Interestingly, if the terms are not independent, $X_n$ may converge to zero.